React component being rendered multiple times
I just started with react and was trying to build some functionalities to understand React better. Here, I am building a search functionality with some fields. On searching, I get a table with the results. In table, I have a delete field functionality for each row item. On clicking of delete a popup should open asking if they want to delete it or not and store the response for further actions.

Here, on click of delete, it looks like the popup component is being called twice (maybe based on number of results currently visible based on the number of log statements printed).
My table comp code:
function DataTable(props) {
    const [searchedData, setsearchedData] = useState({});
    const [openPopup, setOpenPopup] = useState(false);
    const keys = ["Customer Name", "Contact Number", "Contract Number", "Liscence Key"];

    useEffect(() => {
        *getting the data from API and storing in searchData state*
    }, [props.data]);

    function popupResponse(value) {
        setOpenPopup(false);
        if (value) {
            console.log("value is true");
        } else {
            console.log("value is false");
        }
    }

    const deleteKey = useCallback(() => {
        setOpenPopup(true);
        console.log("in delete key");
    }, [setOpenPopup]);

    return (
        <div className="data-table ">
            { Object.keys(searchedData).length > 0 ?
                <div>
                    <table className="data-table__table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                {keys.map((heading, key) => {
                                    return (
                                        <th key={key + heading}>{heading}</th>
                                    );
                                })}
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {searchedData.map((data, key) => <RowData rowData={data} key={key} uniqueKey={key} openPopup={openPopup} deleteLiscense={deleteKey}/>)}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    /** triggering the popup***/
                    {openPopup && <PopUp className="data-table__popup" open={openPopup} close={popupResponse}/>}
                </div>
                : <div className="data-table__no-results">No results found.</div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

RowData component (call deleteLiscense function to set the the of popup to open)
const RowData = ({rowData, uniqueKey, deleteLiscense}) => {
    const values = Object.values(rowData);

    return (
        <>
            <tr key={uniqueKey}>
                {values.map((value) => <td className="" key={uniqueKey + value}>{value}</td>)}
                <td className="" key={uniqueKey}>
                    <button key={uniqueKey} type="button" onClick={() => deleteLiscense}>Delete key</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </>
    );
}

PopUp component:
function PopUp ({open, close}) {
    if (!open) return null;

    const response = (value) => {
        close(value)
    }

    console.log("in popup");

    return (
        <div className="data-table__popup-container">
            <div className="data-table__popup-container--heading"> Are you sure you want to delete the Liscence Key?</div>
            <div className="data-table__popup-container--button-wrapper">
                <button className="button-yes" onClick={() => response(true)}>Yes</button>
                <button className="button-no" onClick={() => response(false)}>No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PopUp;

I tried using callback hook on deleteKey functionality thinking maybe it is getting redefined for each delete key button present in table row, which in return getting called the same number of times as the number of row data present..... triggering popup component. But it didn't resolve the issue.
More observations:
On clicking any of the delete key second time, the popup log doesn't come again.
Thanks!

Any errors warnings in console? Could you please provide minimum reproduceable example?
From what I noticed are:
Firstly, deleteLiscense is not called.
Replace calling from: onClick={() => deleteLiscense} to:
<td className="" key={uniqueKey}>
  <button key={uniqueKey} type="button" onClick={deleteLiscense}>
    Delete key
  </button>
</td>

there is no need to check openPopup variable in the JSX because you check it inside PoPup component and returns null if it is false:
so replace:
{openPopup && <PopUp className="data-table__popup" open={openPopup} close={popupResponse}/>}

to:
<PopUp className="data-table__popup" open={openPopup} close={popupResponse}/>

Secondly, you have a dependency in useCallback function and update this dependecy from this function, it will cause loop of checking.
(calling setOpenPopup inside the useCallback function and also include it in the dependencies array). Every time setOpenPopup is called, it will trigger a re-render, which will then trigger the useCallback``` to be recreated, leading to an infinite loop.
Also, I would replace it to:
const deleteKey = useCallback(() => {
    setOpenPopup(true);
    console.log("in delete key");
}, []);

Or, as an option, transfer  setOpenPopup(true); the code of opening popup:
{
        searchedData.map((data, key) => (
            <RowData
                rowData={data}
                key={key}
                uniqueKey={key}
                openPopup={openPopup}
                deleteLiscense={() => {
                    setOpenPopup(true);
                    deleteKey(); // but this method will be useless if it does not contain any additional logic
                }}
            />
        ));
    }

All in all,
try this code:
const RowData = ({ rowData, uniqueKey, deleteLiscense }) => {
  const values = Object.values(rowData);
  return (
    <>
      <tr key={uniqueKey}>
        {values.map((value) => (
          <td className="" key={uniqueKey + value}>
            {value}
          </td>
        ))}
        <td className="" key={uniqueKey}>
          <button key={uniqueKey} type="button" onClick={deleteLiscense}>
            Delete key
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </>
  );
};

const PopUp = ({ open, close }) => {
  if (!open) return null;

  const response = (value) => {
    close(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="data-table__popup-container">
      <div className="data-table__popup-container--heading">
        {' '}
        Are you sure you want to delete the Liscence Key?
      </div>
      <div className="data-table__popup-container--button-wrapper">
        <button className="button-yes" onClick={() => response(true)}>
          Yes
        </button>
        <button className="button-no" onClick={() => response(false)}>
          No
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const DataTable = (props) => {
  const [searchedData, setsearchedData] = useState({});
  const [openPopup, setOpenPopup] = React.useState(false);
  const keys = [
    'Customer Name',
    'Contact Number',
    'Contract Number',
    'Liscence Key',
  ];
    useEffect(() => {
        *getting the data from API and storing in searchData state*
    }, [props.data]);
  function popupResponse(value) {
    setOpenPopup(false);
    if (value) {
      console.log('value is true');
    } else {
      console.log('value is false');
    }
  }

  const deleteKey = React.useCallback(() => {
    setOpenPopup(true);
    console.log('in delete key');
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="data-table ">
      {Object.keys(searchedData).length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <table className="data-table__table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {keys.map((heading, key) => {
                  return <th key={key + heading}>{heading}</th>;
                })}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {searchedData.map((data, key) => (
                <RowData
                  rowData={data}
                  key={key}
                  uniqueKey={key}
                  openPopup={openPopup}
                  deleteLiscense={deleteKey}
                />
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <PopUp
            className="data-table__popup"
            open={openPopup}
            close={popupResponse}
          />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="data-table__no-results">No results found.</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

